# 'content' property not working with :hover on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, css-content

The `content` property isn't working with a `:hover` selector on any version of IE

HTML:

```
<img class="helpButton" src="images/helpButton.png" alt="Help Button" />
```

CSS:

```
.helpButton:hover {content:url(../images/helpButton-hover.png); cursor: pointer}
```

Note that I do have an HTML 5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`).

Comment: Try putting the URL in quotes: `url("../images/helpButton-hover.png")`

Comment: That is how I had it originally and it wasn't working then either.

Comment: Is it working in other browsers? I just realised what you're doing doesn't make much sense. Instead of setting the content of the image to an image, maybe you should create a wrapper around the image and set the content of that.

Comment: As of CSS 2.1, The `content` property is undefined when used on replaced elements. You're best off not using it.